# Read hive table from mapreduce

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hive

I am currently wrting a mapreduce program to find the difference between two hive tables.
My hive table are partitioned on one or more columns. So teh folder name contains the value of partitioned columns.

Is there any way to read the hive partitioned table.

Can it be read in mapper ?

Comment: You might want to edit your question to reinforce that you are looking for a way to read the get the values of the columns being partitioned on in the mapper. Right now an answerer might thingkyou just want to know how to recursively add all input files to a MapReduce job (which has been addressed on StackOverflow several times). But recreating the table when part of the data is in the input folder structure seems to be an important element of your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the underlying HDFS data will be organised by default in a partitioned hive table as

```
 table/root/folder/x=1/y=1
 table/root/folder/x=1/y=2
 table/root/folder/x=2/y=1
 table/root/folder/x=2/y=2....,
```

You can build each of these input paths in the driver and add them through multiple calls to FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, path).One call per folder path that you built.

Pasted sample code below.Note how paths are added to MyMapper.class.In this sample, I am using MultipleInputs API.Table is partitioned by 'part' and 'xdate'.

```
public class MyDriver extends Configured implements Tool {
    public int run(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Configuration conf = getConf();
        conf.set("mapred.compress.map.output", "true");
        conf.set("mapred.output.compression.type", "BLOCK"); 

        Job job = new Job(conf);
        //set up various job parameters
        job.setJarByClass(MyDriver.class);
        job.setJobName(conf.get("job.name"));
        MultipleInputs.addInputPath(job, new Path(conf.get("root.folder")+"/xdate="+conf.get("start.date")), TextInputFormat.class, OneMapper.class);
        for (Path path : getPathList(job,conf)) {
            System.out.println("path: "+path.toString());
            MultipleInputs.addInputPath(job, path, Class.forName(conf.get("input.format")).asSubclass(FileInputFormat.class).asSubclass(InputFormat.class), MyMapper.class);
        }
        ...
        ...
        return job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : -2;

    }

    private static ArrayList<Path> getPathList(Job job, Configuration conf) {
        String rootdir = conf.get("input.path.rootfolder");
        String partlist = conf.get("part.list");
        String startdate_s = conf.get("start.date");
        String enxdate_s = conf.get("end.date");
        ArrayList<Path> pathlist = new ArrayList<Path>();
        String[] partlist_split = partlist.split(",");
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        Date startdate_d = null;
        Date enxdate_d = null;
        Path path = null;
        try {
            startdate_d = sdf.parse(startdate_s);
            enxdate_d = sdf.parse(enxdate_s);
            GregorianCalendar gcal = new GregorianCalendar();
            gcal.setTime(startdate_d);
            Date d = null;
            for (String part : partlist_split) {
                gcal.setTime(startdate_d);
                do {
                    d = gcal.getTime();
                    FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(conf);
                    path = new Path(rootdir + "/part=" + part + "/xdate="
                            + sdf.format(d));
                    if (fs.exists(path)) {
                        pathlist.add(path);
                    }
                    gcal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 1);
                } while (d.before(enxdate_d));
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return pathlist;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        int res = ToolRunner.run(new Configuration(), new MyDriver(), args);
        System.exit(res);
    }
}
```

Comment: In the MapReduce job you can call `context.getInputSplit()` to get an `InputSplit` object which contains information about where the input came from. `FileSplit` implements `InputSplit` and has a `getPath()` method which you can parse to get the values of the columns being partitioned on.  I can't find any working code examples, so using the [docs](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/FileSplit.html) is probably your best bet. If you are feeling adventurous poking around the [hive source](https://github.com/apache/hive) might be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it can be read in Mapper pretty easily. This answer is based on the idea mentioned by @Daniel Koverman.

With the Context object passed to Mapper.map(), you can get the file split path this way

```
// this gives you the path plus offsets hdfs://.../tablename/partition1=20/partition2=ABC/000001_0:0+12345678
context.ctx.getInputSplit().toString();

// or this gets you the path only
((FileSplit)ctx.getInputSplit()).getPath();
```

Here's a more complete solution that parses out the actual partition value:

```
class MyMapper extends Mapper<KEYIN, VALUEIN, KEYOUT, VALUEOUT> {

    // regex to parse out the /partitionName=partitionValue/ pairs
    private static Pattern partitionRegex = Pattern.compile("(?<=/)(?<name>[_\\-\\w]+)=(?<value>[^/]*)(?=/)");

    public static String parsePartitionValue(String path, String partitionName) throws IllegalArgumentException{
        Matcher m = partitionRegex.matcher(path);
        while(m.find()){
            if(m.group("name").equals(partitionName)){
                return m.group("value");
            }
        }
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(String.format("Partition [%s] not found", partitionName));
    }

    @Override
    public void map(KEYIN key, VALUEIN v, Context ctx) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        String partitionVal = parsePartitionValue(ctx.getInputSplit().toString(), "my_partition_col");
   }
}
```